# Developing Moodle Plugin for control the activity

Tags: php, moodle

I am totally new in this concept. I received a task in which I need to create Moodle plugin for course.
In my course I have two sections where Only videos will be uploaded by teacher. I want to create a plugin to use user webcam while they are playing that video and capture the screenshot. For example, they click on play then webcam will start. so, my question is.
is this possible? and where should I start doing development like in local folder? or in mod folder. I just need some guidance from where I need to start. although I have a simple core code written by myself in php and JavaScript where I can start video when user play video. but I want to integrate that into Moodle, but I don't know from where to start.

I did some research, but it shows the activity plugins should be in /mod folder but I don't know how I should start.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the documentation for developing an activity plugin - although it can be complicated if you are new to Moodle

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Activity_modules

If you are new to Moodle, there is a free beginners course here for developers

https://moodle.academy/enrol/index.php?id=64

Also recording video isn't an easy task - its always worth checking to see if  a plugin already exists - here are contributed plugins

https://moodle.org/plugins/?q=record%20video

Poodll is a popular set of plugins, they already have one for recording video

https://moodle.org/plugins/qtype_poodllrecording

Maybe use one of those as the basis for your plugin

Comment: Thanks For the Answer but I am seeking more depth. I updated the question as well. Actually not record video just want to stream video and where you talking with Poodll its to upload users video Thats not I was looking for. but thanks